# Trying to print ascii representation in C

Tags: c

So I am trying to dynamically generate a box, based on some ascii characters I have defined in a `box_ascii.h`. I am just tying to test my logic and when I get into my for loops I get an error:

```
$ make create_dynamic_box
cc     create_dynamic_box.c   -o create_dynamic_box
create_dynamic_box.c:26:30: error: expected expression
                printf("%c", BOX_TOP_LEFT_CORNER);
                             ^
./box_ascii.h:6:41: note: expanded from macro 'BOX_TOP_LEFT_CORNER'
#define BOX_TOP_LEFT_CORNER             = "\214" // ╓
```

My google research on the error usually mean I need something like `int b = a`, which basically tells me that something doesn't have a type or has the wrong type(?)

Any ways the code is:

**box_ascii.h**

```
#ifndef __box_ascii_h__
#define __box_ascii_h__

// Might not be exact Ascii Characters but they come from:
// http://www.asciitable.com/
#define BOX_TOP_LEFT_CORNER             = "\214" // ╓
#define BOX_TOP_RIGHT_CORNER            = "\187" // ╖
#define BOX_BOTTOM_LEFT_CORNER          = "\200" // ╚
#define BOX_BOTTOM_RIGHT_CORNER         = "\188" // ╛
#define BOX_SIDE                        = "\186" // ║
#define BOX_TOP_BOTTOM                  = "\205" // ═

#endif
```

**create_dynamic_box.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "box_ascii.h"

void print_border(int width, int height);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if(argc < 3) {
        printf("Mustenter width and height.");
        return -1;
    }


    print_border(atoi(argv[1]), atoi(argv[2]));

    return 0;
}

void print_border(int width, int height) {
    int row = 0;
    int col = 0;

    for (row = 0; row < width; row ++) {
        for (col = 0; col < height; col++) {
            if (row == 0 && col == 0) {
                printf("%c", BOX_TOP_LEFT_CORNER); // error thrown here.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Whats going on? is it because I am using `%c` ??**

Comment: None of those characters are ASCII.

Comment: also: the `#define`s define strings, not characters.

Comment: "Extended ASCII" is dangerously ambiguous. Only the first 128 are ASCII, the rest are non-standard and vary from place to place. The character set shown at asciitable.com is the old IBM-PC code page 437, common in the old MSDOS days. It is not Windows code page 1252, Mac OS Roman, ISO-8859-1 (Linux standard), or any other standard set you are likely to have on your machine today, so even if you fix your code, it is unlikely you will see those characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error messages come about because macros do text substitution - they are not named values.

So

```
#define BOX_TOP_LEFT_CORNER             = "\214"
printf("%c", BOX_TOP_LEFT_CORNER);
```

will be seen by the compiler as

```
printf("%c", = "\214");
```

That has two problems.  Firstly, the `=` is misplaced.   Second, `%c` causes `printf()` to expect a single character, whereas `"\214"` is an array of two characters (`'\214'` and `'\0'`).

So, the `=` sign needs to be removed from the macro.

If you want to use the `%c` format, change the macro definition to use single quote characters (`'`)

```
#define BOX_TOP_LEFT_CORNER           '\214'
```

If you want the macros to be multi-character strings, then use the `%s` format.

Either way, don't supply a string where a single character is expected, or vice versa.

Also:  The characters like `\214` are extended ASCII (which is not well defined) not ASCII.

Answer (score 0):

Your BOX_* macros define strings, not characters.  They should be:

```
#define BOX_TOP_LEFT_CORNER '\214' //
```

and so forth for the rest of the macros.

In C, `\xyz' defines a character whose octal code is *xyz*.

Reference [here.](http://www.cs.mun.ca/~michael/c/constants.html)